# PHP mail function Carbon Copies

Tags: php, email

I am having trouble with php's mail function.

This is the code:

```
    public function send_email($emailInfo)
    {
    // email fields: to, from, subject, and so on
    $to             = $emailInfo['toEmail'];
    $from           = $emailInfo['fromEmail'];
    $subject        = $emailInfo['subject'];
    $message        = $emailInfo['message'];
    //$message          = $this->base_directory.'/application/views/emailtemplates/ticketresponse'($emailInfo['viewVars'], true);
    $headers        = 'From: '.$emailInfo['fromEmail'].' <'.$emailInfo['fromEmail'].'>';

    // boundary
    $semi_rand = md5(time());
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

    // headers for attachment
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

    if (is_array($emailInfo['cc']))
        {
        $headers .= 'Cc: ';
        foreach ($emailInfo['cc'] as $cc)
            {
            $headers .= $cc. ",";
            }
        $headers = substr($headers, 0, -1);
        $headers .= "\r\n";
        }   

    // multipart boundary
    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

    // send
    @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, '-f'.$emailInfo['fromEmail']);
    }
```

the function does indeed send emails, and the array of cc recipients is indeed populated, however these recipients do not receive any emails.

Comment: What error you get? just  var_dump($emailInfo); and check you get the recipients email here.

Comment: What version of php are you doing this in?

Comment: If you email yourself (just plain `mail("you@yor.com","test","test");`), do you receive that email?

Comment: I have tested it as i have all the test emails. I get the To address email but not ccs. the cc section in headers echos like....Cc: email@hotmail.co.uk, mrsorbose@hotmail.com,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any additional headers supplied must be seperated by `\r\n` ie, `CRLF`. You are doing this for the cc header, but not for the others. This might have an impact.

```
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n";
$headers .= " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend avoiding PHP's built-in `mail()` function. It's really not fit for purpose for anything beyond the most basic panic email to the site administrator.

For anything more than that (including simple stuff like adding CC addresses), I recommend using a decent mailer class, such as [PHPMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/). It will make your code *much* simpler and more reliable.

Hope that helps.